# Access SQL - DateDiff Where it only looks for values that have existed over 2 weeks in the database

Tags: ms-access

```
SELECT        SerialNumber
FROM            Warranty
WHERE        (ABS(DateDiff('d', EndDate1, EndDate2)) > 7)
```

I currently have a query that shows me the Serial Numbers that have a difference of more than 7 days between the 2 dates. I want to add another condition where it will skip checking Serial Numbers that have been added to the database in the last 2 weeks

Comment: What's your field name for "Date Added"?

Comment: I do not have one, that would probably help I suppose. I was wondering if there was something I could do without having to add a new field to the database

Comment: It's hard to filter on a field that doesn't exist.  ;o)

Comment: so WHEN i create this Date Added feild :P Would it be something like .GetNow() - 14 ?

Comment: In Access you just need to use Date().  So, it'd be something like MyNewDateField >= DateAdd("d", -14, Date())

Comment: Now() will give you also the time in day. If your saving the data in a date/Time field, better have the time Info...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to go ahead and add this as an answer, to make it clearer.

```
SELECT       SerialNumber
FROM         Warranty
WHERE        (ABS(DateDiff('d', EndDate1, EndDate2)) > 7)
     AND     MyNewDateField >= DateAdd("d", -14, Date())
```

Essentially, this adds -14 days to the current date (or subtracts 2 weeks), and then only takes records where the DateAdded field (aka "MyNewDateField") is greater than, or equal to, that date.  So, this will keep all records where DateAdded is within the most recent 2 weeks.